# Ignore folder except root

Tags: git

I need to ignore bin folders except the one placed in the root. Here is what I have added to .gitignore:

```
!/bin
bin
```

But git ignores root bin folder and marks it for delete after I execute

```
git rm --cached -r .
git add .
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Flip the two lines:

```
bin/
!/bin/
```

Comment: It worked, thank you! But could you please clarify why it works only this way?

Comment: From the manpage: "An optional prefix `!` which negates the pattern; any matching file excluded **by a previous pattern** will become included again.".